# Getting mouse coordinates without event in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to get mouse coordinates in my program. I know I can do it using a MOUSE_MOVE event but I would like to know if there is a more simple and direct way.

Is it possible to get mouse coordinates without using events in as3?

Comment: do you need the coordinates relative to the stage or some other displayobject? either way, have you tried using the mouseX and mouseY properties?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The stage has mouseX and mouseY properties that you can access at any time.